# What fittings do I need to replumb

Tags: plumbing

Follow up to previous post, trying to choose what fittings to grab from the store.
Will probably have to replace section with multiple joins (see picture, A).

What sections/fittings should I use to replumb this without the disposal?
The bottom of the sink with the disposal is a little higher up than the other
In other words, help me go shopping :)
https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=end+outlet+continuous

I think for section B, I can cut after the elbow and tie in a branch tailpiece like this
https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-1-1-2-in-Plastic-Direct-Connect-Branch-Tailpiece-7-8-in-OD-Outlet/1088263

For section C, I might need an elbow or two

Instead of replacing section B, I could replace section D with a tail piece with the dishwasher connection like this [link](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-1-1-2-in-Plastic-Direct-Connect-Branch-Tailpiece/3446684), cut to length

[image]

Comment: Honestly, if you're shopping any of the big box stores, buy double what you need (and then some), keep the receipt, and return everything left over in perfect condition.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Or keep them for later use: the Spares box. But good suggestion.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate my technique exactly. And also why I have a large bin of left over plumbing and electrical parts. I never quite get around to returning them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got a new strainer and then mixed/matched some pieces I grabbed at lowes to connect over to the trap.  
No more garbage disposal!
Note:  use hacksaw on pvc drain pipe, pvc cutters will break it.
1 branch tail piece for dishwasher
Couple bags of fittings with direct connect type elbows, all 1.5 inch
**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Also, grabbed some of these to keep larger solids out of the pipes.
[image]